# Rotation of character affects eye movement wierdly

Tags: animation, rigging

When I rotate my character the eyes rotates in a wierd angle. I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MfxTdq0V2I&list=LLHLJ8TJSfN5oli9iZK6e99Q&index=19&t=253s I'm new so I really don't know what how to explain it... Think it has something to do with local/world space in the copy rotation constraint. Would be happy if anyone could help!

Comment: make sure you put the Armature above the Lattice in the modifier stack. If it doesn't fix the problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am a little new to Blender, but I think I have an idea for something you could try. Perhaps switching the local space on the copy rotation modifier to local with parent will help work`things out. Just set both fields to local with parent. If you don't set them both to that mode will look glitchy and move out of place. I sure hope that helps!